# How do I make the p_adjust function from hdm package work?

Tags: lasso-regression, adjustment

I’m trying to fit **lasso regressions in R**, using the rlassoEffects function from the hdm package. I'm new to lasso procedure but so far I have managed to make it work. However, **I now would like to use the function p_adjust to adjust my p-values (with Romano-Wolf method), and I'm struggling with that.**

I've managed to make it work once with my first lasso model, but not with a second one. I've received the following error message: **"Error in colMeans(v^2) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions**". I guess the structure of my second model must be a bit different from the expected structure for input to the p_adjust function, but I don't see what's wrong.

This is what my first model looks like:

```
lasso_1 = hdm::rlassoEffects(x = covariates_matrix, y = outcome_vector, index = c(1:2), method = "double selection")

summary(lasso_1)

[1] "Estimates and significance testing of the effect of target variables"
             Estimate. Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
treatment1     0.11926    0.09154   1.303    0.193
treatment2     0.10241    0.08389   1.221    0.222
```

Then I ran this code `p_adjust(lasso_1, method = "RW", B = 1000)` and it worked fine.

And this is the second model:

```
lasso_2 = hdm::rlassoEffect(x = covariates_matrix, y = outcome_vector, d = treatment_vector, method = "double selection")

summary(lasso_2)

[1] "Estimates and significance testing of the effect of target variables"
   Estimate. Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
d1   -0.3906     0.1965  -1.988   0.0468 *
```

And this time I got the error message when using p_adjust. I've tried to manually add an intercept term to my lasso_2 object, just to see if p_adjust works better once my model has a second row:

```
coefficients <- lasso_2$coefficients
se <- lasso_2$se
pval <- lasso_2$pval
t <- lasso_2$t

intercept <- c(intercept = 0)

# Combine intercept and coefficients
new_coefficients <- c(intercept, coefficients)
new_se <- c(intercept, se)
new_pval <- c(intercept, pval)
new_t <- c(intercept, t)


# Create a modified rlassoEffect object
lasso_2_with_intercept <- lasso_2

lasso_2_with_intercept$coefficients <- new_coefficients
lasso_2_with_intercept$se <- new_se
lasso_2_with_intercept$pval <- new_pval
lasso_2_with_intercept$t <- new_t
```

But when I run `p_adjust(lasso_2_with_intercept, method = "RW", B = 1000)`, I still get the same error message... So it seems that p_adjust expects a specific data structure that's not provided in my lasso_2 object, even with a few quick modifications.

Do you think the error comes from differences in the specification of the lasso models? Or is it just because I have only one treatment variable in my second model? But surely p_adjust also works when you just have one treatment variable? Or maybe some of you can recommend another package that works better to adjust the p-values of lasso regressions?

I'm not including a reproducible example because my code is very long and based on a very large dataset, but I'm hoping that someone can detect some obvious mistake based on what I've mentioned, because I'm quite new to these lasso procedures and not a pro in R.